# Why the composer create-project laravel / laravel sicovet "5.5. *" command fails

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

Look at this image and help please

The image shows that Composer is installed, I also use a proxy for the connection which I configured before executing the composer command but still it still gives me the error that I attached in the image

[image]

This my proxy connection

[image]

Comment: I would expect it's because your proxy cannot reach https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json

Comment: why? configuration?

Comment: by the browser I have access to that address

Comment: does your browser go through the proxied connection

Comment: Yes, the browser goes through the proxy connection

Comment: look the picture, proxy connection

Comment: Your https proxy is pointing to an http connection?

Comment: yes http://proxy.vc.onei.cu/

Comment: any help, please